# Not able to change x ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot

I am struggling to change to change the x_ticks labels in this plot. I want to replace 0, 1 ,2 with  ['Decision Tree','Random Forest','SVM with SMOTE'].

```py
# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(14,6))

ax.set_xlabel("Machine learning model",fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Score",fontsize=20)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
# plot_df.rename(index={0: 'Decision Tree', 1: 'Random Forest', 2: 'SVM with SMOTE'})

locs, labels = plt.xticks()
print("locs",locs)
print("labels",labels)

labels = ['Decision Tree','Random Forest','SVM with SMOTE']

ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plot_df.plot.bar(ax=ax,width=0.5,stacked = False,fontsize = 11)
```

Printed output:

```
locs [0.  0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1. ]
labels <a list of 6 Text xticklabel objects>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your `set_xtickslabels` and change this in your code:

```
plot_df.plot.bar(x=labels, ax=ax,width=0.5,stacked = False,fontsize = 11)
```

Comment: I got this unfortunately: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Decision Tree', 'Random Forest', 'SVM with SMOTE'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 0):

The best way was just changing the dataframe I was using in the plot:

```py
plot_df = plot_df.set_index([pd.Index(['Decision Tree','Random Forest','SVM with SMOTE'])])
plot_df
```

Also, styling the ticks:

```py
chart = plot_df.plot.bar(ax=ax, width=0.5, stacked=False, fontsize=11)
chart.set_xticklabels(
    chart.get_xticklabels(),
    rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontsize = 16
)
```

[image]

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58955511/2) to the question [Not able to change x ticks in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955511/not-able-to-change-x-ticks-in-matplotlib) by the OP [meerkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971344/meerkat) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>